# Unable to install Microsoft Office 2001 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ms-office

I want to install Microsoft Office 2001 on a Mac OS X whose version is 10.6.8.
There is a folder  and it has folders named Clipart, Office, Read Me, RESOURCE.FRK, Shared Applications and Templates. It also has Microsoft Word, Excel, Powerpoint and Entourage, these are Unix Executable Files.
I'd like to know how I can install Office 2001 on this machine. I don't have any prior Mac OS experience. Thanks.

Comment: What form is the installation media? That shipped as a CD if I recall and you ran the installer app to perform the install. If you can edit some details in the post above, the likelihood of an answer increases. Also, have a look at [help] to make sure this is on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Office 2001 isn't designed to run natively on OS X. It needs either OS 9 or some form of translation software.

Apple used to provide this in the form of [Rosetta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)), which was part of the OS X operating system until OS X 10.6 in 2009.
It used to be available as an additional download by launching the App Store, or by installing it from the 'Extras' folder on the original 10.6 installer disks.

I'm not certain if Office 2001 is even actually too old to run under Rosetta, or whether it must be run specifically under the [Classic Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Environment), i.e. OS9.
[Office X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Microsoft_Office_2001_and_v._X) was released to specifically address that.

The simplest workarounds might be

- Get a newer version of Office, that supports OS X [possibly costly]
- Get [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/), which ought to be able to work with most Office documents, regardless of age [free]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know a painless way for me to open Office 2001 files on OS X? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Office 2001 files should be openable on any newer version. Alternatively, [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org) might do the job, for free.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X 10.6 and the hardware it runs on is too new to run Office 2001.

Office 2001 required Mac OS 8, 9 or Classic. To run Classic under OS X, you need a Power PC based Mac, and up to Mac OS X version 10.4. 
Your options:

- run Office 2001 in SheepShaver which emulates Mac OS 9 on a current Mac. This is a bit tricky to setup. You need a copy of OS 9, a copy of a suitable Macintosh ROM. Once setup SheepShaver should work well for Office 2001. [SheepShaver Wrapper](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/sheepshaverwrapper.html) provides good instructions and a wrapper tool to make it easier to setup.
- A number of apps can read an write Office documents. Apple's Pages, Numbers and Keynote do a good job of importing most of MS formats.
- Mac OS X's built-in TextEdit does a reasonable job of importing most simple Word documents.
- LibreOffice or OpenOffice are open source and do a great job of dealing with MS Office Documents. *(LibreOffice is a fork of OpenOffice. I understand Libre has more development and momentum,  but I have not followed this closely.)*

Comment: Or you could install pages numbers and keynote. I think they should have come with your mac.